# Is it possible to detect the exact location of the subscriber who click the link in email?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-studio, history-tracking, email-tracking, tracking-extract

If subscriber clicked any link in email. How to track the exact location of the subscriber like (state) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that in the email.

It would require client-side script as part of your email that is executed when someone opens / clicks reading out the IP on their machine (= the client) - this is blocked in emails, as running script on somebody's machine could easily be used for exploits. So email as a technology doesn't allow for it.

In contrast, e.g. in mobile push you *can* get information about the client device, including where it is, see mobile push data view (e.g. here https://github.com/rodrigofreitasit/data-view-mobile-push-Mkt-Cloud ), which is also why mobile push beacons and geofencing exist, but you've never heard of, say "email geofencing".

==

If you own the web page that people are accessing through the link -> here is where you will be able to read out IPs accessing your page. This can be done (and likely is already, through some web tracking tool). Note that IPs are not 100% deterministic, think proxies / VPNs etc.

What you should do is align on a common tracking mechanism (link parameters that are in your links, and expected on page) so that the people that click your link can also be matched in your web tracker.